# Can you build Ember Component so that it can co-exist and interop with other web components?

Tags: ember.js, web-component

I want to know if you can create Ember Component in the way it can:

- render with other web components (say, built by Polymer or X-Tag)
- interoperate through parameter-passing and/or events

inside the application that is NOT built by emberjs?

---

So far I've create web components using these documents as a guide and make them interoperate each other to some dgree:
(sadly, I can only post link to one document so I choose the Polymer one)

- Vanilla JS
- Polymer - [Custom Element Interoperability](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/polymer-xtag-vanilla.html)
- React (Reactive Elements)
- X-Tags

but I can't seem to find good example of how you can create and use Ember Component inside other JS framework (let's say in angular) and wondering if Ember Component is expected to be used within emberjs at the moment, or I'm missing something obvious and it can behave like other ordinary custom element.

If anyone can point me to some project repo, example or website that illustrate if this can be done, that would be much appreciated. Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Might worth checking out this tweet. https://twitter.com/michaellnorth/status/563848427574796288 AFAIK it is not possible to use ember components in other libraries.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question and providing a link to interesting  meet up. I will keep my eye on it (I live in Canada so it's too far to actually attend it but still nice to know people are talking about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time the standard for web components has not been finalized. See [this link](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/components#w3c_all) where the W3C is tracking their progress.  Only once the specification has been finalized and implemented by the modern browsers will we have a shot at re-usable web components. In all likelihood, each JavaScript framework will implement their own abstractions on top of the web components spec. I personally anticipate a number of years of fragmentation before we have a chance at achieving the re-usability you describe in your question.

In summary, it is **not possible** to re-use ember components in other frameworks *at this time*.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question and confirming what I'm trying to do is still not possible. I will keep my eye on the W3C link you've provided.

Comment: Does this warrant being marked as the answer or would you like further information?

Comment: Sure I'lll mark your answer as accepted answer now but if anyone bump into this question later and have any new/updated information, I'd like to hear and hopefully it also benefit others as well - I can't be the only guy who like Ember Component to work in more generic form :)